# Extension of Scalars as Equivalence Classes

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Given a ring morphism $f\colon R\to S$, there is a functor $f_!\colon RMod\to SMod$, $N\mapsto S\otimes_R N$ called "the extension of scalars".

My confusion arises from a statement in nLab's [article](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/extension+of+scalars) which states that

> For N∈SMod (sic) the elements of f!N are equivalence classes of pairs (s,n)∈S×N under the equivalence relation (s⋅f(r),n)=(s,r⋅n) for all s∈S; the left S-action is given by s'⋅(s,n)=(s'⋅s,n).

[First off, there is a typo and it should say $N\in RMod$ and not $N\in SMod$.]

My question is how does the tensor $S$-module $S\otimes_R N$ which consists of sums of simple tensors (and we stress that these elements may have no simple representation) be in a one-to-one correspondence with a factor of the Cartesian product $S\times N$ especially since there is a bijection between simple tensors in $S\otimes_R N$ and the equivalence classes?

Comment: What does an element of $S \times N$ look like?  Is it also a sum of "simple things"?

Comment: The  exact way to see this is via the universal property. [ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_modules#Definition ]

Comment: $\theta(s\otimes n + s' \otimes n') = \theta(s\otimes n) + \theta(s' \otimes n')$, which images are "simple products" in $S \times N$.  Your conditions (seem to) ensure that the equivalence class containing $s\otimes n + s' \otimes n'$ contains only one element, so $\theta$ is one-to-one here, but no promises elsewhere.

Comment: @EricTowers Thanks for the replies. I think I am understanding the statement now. It does not suggest that $S\otimes_R N\cong \frac{S\times N}{\sim}$ where $\sim$ is the above equivalence. Instead it is just reformulating how to construct the tensor product given such a bilinear map with such an action.

Comment: Yes.  Correct.  Exactly.